# Mid 20th century post-apocalyptic novel which utilized the term "the Mysteries"?

Tags: story-identification, novel, post-apocalyptic, alternate-history

"The Mysteries" were descriptions of past cultural traditions such as religion or ethnicity which became mangled when half-remembered by survivors of an apocalyptic war or pestilence.

I especially remember the term "Joosh Mystery" used to refer to Jewish beliefs and history.

Does anyone know the name and author of a novel published as a paperback book with this prop for its backstory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Novel '[Gunner Cade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gunner_Cade)' by C.M. Kornbluth & Judith Merril contains both the phrase "Joosh Mystery" and extensive reference to "mysteries". There seems to be a dystopian rather than post-apocalyptic theme though...

> The novel deals with the transformation of Cade, the title character,
>   from a loyal member of the elite police force of an authoritarian
>   interplanetary regime into an individualistic rebel. Kornbluth and
>   Merril crafted the novel to appeal to Astounding editor John W.
>   Campbell, using Fritz Leiber's Gather, Darkness! as their model. "We
>   did a really interesting analytical breakdown of what Campbell would
>   and wouldn't buy", Merril later wrote. "The scientific stuff had to be
>   there, but the sort of spiritual fantasy element had to be there as
>   well. Also, the novel had to contain the sort of humor that made sense
>   to Campbell".

Comment: I agree about "dystopian" but apparently it's not available as a tag. (What's wrong with saying "thank you" for making the-next-to-impossible easy?) I just now bought a copy of  Ace Double D-227, which I haven't read in 50+ years!

Comment: @Russell - http://38.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_me08kzM0fu1r0cysz.gif